# jupyter nbconvert: convert to markdown and/or html excluding slides marked as `skip`

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

## Background

I have a notebook which I can export to reveal.js slides using:

```
jupyter nbconvert "${executed_nb_path}" \
    --to slides \
    --SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll=True \
    --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True \
    --no-prompt
```

It **excludes** cells with cell metadata:

```
{
  "slideshow": {
    "slide_type": "skip"
  }
}
```

## Question

How do I export to other outputs formats, such as `html` or `md`, and *apply the same preprocessing with respect to cell metadata*? I would like to be able to do this at the command line if possible (e.g. by setting command line arguments for the preprocessing), as opposed to creating a python script.

## What I have tried

1. Tried to work out the correct "traitlet" argument to add: docs [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#execution-arguments-traitlets)

   - no dice with `--TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags='slideshow.slide_type="skip"'`
2. Looked at the source code to see how the preprocessing is done:

   - the entry point for `jupyter nbconvert --to slides ...` is [`nbconvert.exporters:SlidesExporter`](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/957c2e2476e1106fd4976af7d104c01cd5bb7562/setup.py#L265)
   - `nbconvert.exporters.slides._RevealMetadataPreprocessor` contains: [`if cell.metadata.slide_type not in {'notes', 'skip'}`](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/exporters/slides.py#L32)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TagRemoveProprocessor](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/removing_cells.html#removing-pieces-of-cells-using-cell-tags) requires `tags` in cell metadata to work

You can add tags by going to View -> Cell toolbar -> Tags.

If you added `skip` tag after which cell metadata  would be something like this:

```
"metadata": {
 "tags": [
  "skip"
 ]
},
```

For eg: If you want to convert it to `markdown` then you would pass `markdown` as a value to `--to` flag

```
jupyter nbconvert sample.ipynb \
    --to markdown \
    --no-prompt \
    --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags={\"skip\"} \
    --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True
```

For latest [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) command can be rewritten like:

```
jupyter nbconvert sample.ipynb \
    --to markdown \
    --no-prompt \
    --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags "skip" \
    --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True
```

[nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) support html, markdown as output, For other supported output check [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#supported-output-formats)

### Solution

You can use any of these commands to add skip tag to metadata which contain slideshow key and then use that with [TagRemoveProprocessor](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/removing_cells.html#removing-pieces-of-cells-using-cell-tags) to remove cell

#### [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
cat sample.ipynb | jq '.cells[].metadata |= if .slideshow.slide_type == "skip" then (.+ {tags: ["skip"]}) else . end' > new_sample.ipynb
```

#### [SED](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) - (required changes for mac)

```
sed '/"slideshow": {/N;/.*"slide_type":\ "skip"/i\ \ \ \ "tags":["skip"],' sample.ipynb > new_sample.ipynb
```

And then you can use above [jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) command to remove cell.

**Notes:**

- `TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True` removes all input cell does nothing to output cell
- `TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags` removes input output cell that contain specified tag
- `TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_input_tags` removes input cell that contain specified tag does nothing to output cell
- `TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_all_outputs_tags` removes all output cell that contain specified tag does not remove related input tag
- both commands can be added together to create one-liner.
- As pointed out by @JamesOwers - If you are on mac for [SED](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) command you need to use `gnu-sed` that can be installed using brew - `brew install gnu-sed` then just change `sed` to `gsed`.

Comment: Thanks @Chandan, I appreciate your clear and careful answer. I allows me to skip cells, but does not answer my question: it would involve me me going through my notebook and adding a whole new set of metadata - this is doable of course, but is an issue because these two sets of metadata will not necessarily stay in sync. I already have the slide metadata describing which cells to skip. As such, this answer does not solve the problem of excluding slides marked with `slideshow.slide_type="skip"` metadata.

Comment: @JamesOwers please check i have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you again! I think we're nearly there, but the current solution will skip all cells with *any* slideshow metadata. We need to constrain to cells with `slide_type="skip"` e.g. cells with metadata:
```
{
  "slideshow": {
    "slide_type": "skip"
  }
}
```

Comment: @JamesOwers I have updated `jq`, `sed` commands for `"slideshow": { "slide_type": "skip" }}`.

Comment: I can confirm this works. I very much appreciate you coming back twice to answer. I'm on mac but, for the benefit of others, you can `brew install gnu-sed` and use the command as above, else you'll need to edit the `sed` command slightly.

Comment: @JamesOwers thanks can you help me with the mac option i don't have mac so i can't test it to confirm its working.

Comment: Ofc, it's simply to: 1) install the tool (`brew install gnu-sed`), then 2) `sed` -> `gsed` in the command. Mac's default `sed` doesn't work quite the same and that command will error (I think! I was testing with the `-i` flag). I think you can leave your answer as is tbh, but feel free to add a note about gsed :). I have accepted it as is.